# WordPress Form Not Submitting to Database If Autocompleted

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, forms

Well, as the title states, it doesn't submit to the database if it's autocompleted, but does if it has not been. I do not want to disable autocompletion, and I'm not sure why it's doing this. I have no errors in my log files for both PHP and MySQL in my MAMP folder, either. Lastly, it does redirect to the confirmation page even though it doesn't submit to the database when autofilled.

My Code:

```
function request_private() {

if(isset($_POST['privateSubmit'])) {

    global $wpdb;

    $name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privateName']);
    $phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privatePhone']);
    $email = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privateEmail']);
    $time = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privateTime']);
    $people = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privatePeople']);
    $type = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privateType']);
    $requests = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privateRequests']);
    $filter = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privateFilter']);
    $antiSpam = sanitize_text_field($_POST['privateAntiSpam']);

    if ($antiSpam === '8' && $name !== '' && $name !== ' ' && $phone !== '' && $phone !== ' ' && $time !== '' && $time !== ' ' && $people !== '' && $people !== ' ' && $type !== '' && $type !== ' ' && $filter === '') {

        $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'requests';

        $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'email' => $email,
            'time' => $time,
            'people' => $people,
            'type' => $type,
            'requests' => $requests
        );

        $format = array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        );

        $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);

        $url = get_page_by_title('Confirmation');

        wp_redirect( get_permalink($url) );

        $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');

        $admin_message = 'You have received a new private event from ' . $name . ' on/at ' . $time . '. More information can be found on WordPress under Forms > Private Events.';
        $customer_message = '' . $name . ', this is an email to confirm that we have received your request for a private event on ' . $time . '. We look forward to seeing you!';

        mail($admin_email, "Private Event Request Confirmation", $admin_message);
        mail($email, "Private Event Request Notification", $customer_message);

        exit();

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

}

  add_action('init', 'request_private');
```

FAILED HTTP POST Request:

Request URL: http://localhost:5757/private-events/?ckcachecontrol=1537755652

Request Method: POST

Status Code: 302 Found

Remote Address: [::1]:5757

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 02:20:59 GMT

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

Location: http://localhost:5757/confirmation/

Server: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.1 
mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 222

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_cd9b744c619529c4988e0e94344eaf12=admin%7C1537891968%7CRSrR6dTZc4Vrj76lhdSRST31GpY77NksQJGVz2LcItd%7Ce1ce57f16867a7ab2c527d02f11bb3f4390341db21a2623048226998f1550ff8; wp-settings-1=mfold%3Do%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dtinymce%26post_dfw%3Doff%26hidetb%3D0%26editor_expand%3Don; wp-settings-time-1=1537719169

Host: localhost:5757

Origin: http://localhost:5757

Referer: http://localhost:5757/private-events/?ckcachecontrol=1537755652

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6)

AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36

ckcachecontrol: 1537755652

privateName: name example

privateEmail: email@email.com

privatePhone: 1111111111

privateTime: asd

privatePeople: asd

privateType: asd

privateRequests: asd

privateFilter:

privateAntiSpam: 8

privateSubmit: Submit Request

SUCCESSFUL HTTP POST REQUEST:

Request URL: http://localhost:5757/private-events/

Request Method: POST

Status Code: 302 Found

Remote Address: [::1]:5757

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 02:43:14 GMT

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

Location: http://localhost:5757/confirmation/

Server: Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.2.1 mod_ssl/2.2.34 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.1

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 208

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_cd9b744c619529c4988e0e94344eaf12=admin%7C1537891968%7CRSrR6dTZc4Vrj76lhdSRST31GpY77NksQJGVz2LcItd%7Ce1ce57f16867a7ab2c527d02f11bb3f4390341db21a2623048226998f1550ff8; wp-settings-1=mfold%3Do%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dtinymce%26post_dfw%3Doff%26hidetb%3D0%26editor_expand%3Don; wp-settings-time-1=1537719169

Host: localhost:5757

Origin: http://localhost:5757

Referer: http://localhost:5757/private-events/

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36

privateName: name example

privateEmail: email@email.com

privatePhone: 1111111111

privateTime: asd

privatePeople: asd

privateType: asd

privateRequests:

privateFilter:

privateAntiSpam: 8

privateSubmit: Submit Request

Answer (score 0):

Whether a form is filled out using auto-complete or manually should not matter. If the generated HTTP requests are identical and sent to a server in identical state then the requests should be processed the same. I see only three possibilities.

1. The HTTP requests are not identical.
2. The HTTP server was not in an identical state.
3. The test procedure is somehow incorrect.

I diffed the successful and failing HTTP requests and there were some differences:

1. The failing HTTP request has an additional ckcachecontrol query parameter and ckcachecontrol POST parameter.
2. The POST parameter privateRequests has different values.
3. The Date, Content-Length and Referer HTTP fields are different.

The first experiment to try is to remove the ckcachecontrol query parameter and ckcachecontrol POST parameter from the failing request. (Is it possible that the ckcachecontrol query parameter enables a server cache to return the HTTP redirect to "http://localhost:5757/confirmation/" bypassing the PHP processing?)

If this fails to solve the problem I have more experiments to run. There has to be an explanation.